# Annoying white space to the right of my mobile website

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I open my website http://earncsgoitems.com/ through a mobile device I notice a white area to its right (which can be seen by scrolling horizontally). I've been trying to figure out what's causing it for hours to no avail. I have tried using "overflow-x: hidden;" to disable scrolling but my header doesn't function properly when I implement that in my CSS.

How can I remove this white area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fixed width in the #rewards div, just remove it:

```css
#rewards {
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 1170px;      /* <--- Remove this line */
}
```

Comment: I did that and I ended up with 3 rewards next to each other instead of 4. How can I fit 4 rewards without using such a property?

Comment: @Adept: Remove the `margin-left: 2px` too.

Comment: @Adept You'll have to adjust the width/margin/padding/border/box-sizing (I didn't actually look at the site, but the sizing is usually the problem)

Comment: @Illmari Karonen Worked like a charm, great! Thanks a lot!